# NoRouteToHostException in Hadoop cluster when simulating a node failure?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a hadoop cluster that I'm required to perform some fault tolerant testing on. During  testing when a node in a Hadoop(HDFS) cluster is shutdown (to simulate a failure) & its IP address no longer exists in the network - HDFS on the remaining nodes is hanging indefinitely with NoRouteToHostExceptions - is there a way to fix this?

On a side note if I kill the hadoop processes on the node but leave the node running (ip address remains valid on the network), the fault tolerance works fine, there is no hanging & everything works fine.

I have already seen the explanation for this exception here:
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost

If it's not possible to fix this issue - I thought Hadoop clusters were supposed to be fault tolerant to node failures?

Thanks

***Update based on the first answer:***
Yes the services have been fully replicated across all nodes for high availability - it's a deliberate part of the design.

(1) If I actually just kill the Hadoop services on the node but leave the node running (its IP address remains valid on the network) - the issue does not occur and the remaining nodes continue as normal with no loss of data (as the data was fully replicated across all nodes).

(2) The issue occurs when I shutdown the node and its IP is no longer available on the network, the remaining nodes can no longer make a TCP connection to it (as the IP no longer exists) and so they just hang indefinitely with NoRouteToHostExceptions - this is the issue I’m trying to fix

Again the irony is if the IP address remains valid but the Hadoop services are down, this hanging issue does not happen - (1) above - the remaining nodes can still make TCP connections to the “simulated failed” node but the Hadoop services are down.

It's not a networking issue - it’s a controlled test to simulate node failures in the cluster.
When the node is shutdown to simulate a failure - it’s obvious that the IP address will no longer be valid on the network. The issue we are having is that the Hadoop cluster can’t seem to handle this situation when the IP address of the node no longer exists. What we were expecting (or maybe hoping is a better word), when the remaining nodes in the Hadoop cluster encounter a NoRouteToHostException, they would assume this node had failed and would just continue as normal without it. If this is not possible, that’s ok, I just needed to find out for sure and that I wasn’t missing something. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> I thought Hadoop clusters were supposed to be fault tolerant to node failures?

Only *to a point*.

- If you have one NameNode, and it goes down, nothing is usable. You cannot read/write/process data.
- If all DataNodes for a replica of a HDFS block are down, you can't read that data.
- If the ResourceManager is down, you cannot run MapReduce, Spark, etc. jobs.

It's not clear which machine you had shutdown, but I would suggest looking into the NameNode & ResourceManager HA configurations as well as set the default replication factor for DataNodes to at least 3.

However, "no route to host" is not a Hadoop problem, and isn't something to be fixed at the application level. As mentioned on the wiki,

> These are all network configuration/router issues. As it is your network, ***only you*** can find out and track down the problem.

Which basically means, you need to enure your routing tables & DNS servers or hosts files know where a server IP exists.